# Interior of a family of sets

Tags: general-topology

I've the following result: Given any family of set $\{S_k\}_{k\in K}$, then 
$$\tag{*}
\operatorname{cl}\left(\prod_{k\in K}S_k\right)
=\prod_{k\in K}\operatorname{cl}(S_k),
$$
and I'm looking for 
$$\tag{a}
\operatorname{int}\left(\prod_{k\in K}S_k\right)
=\prod_{k\in K}\operatorname{int}(S_k).
$$

Further I use, with some freedom in the notation,
$$\tag{b}
\left(\prod_{k\in K} S_k\right)^C =\bigcup_{k\in K} \left(S_k{}^C\times\prod_{j\in K-k} X_j\right)
$$
and
$$\tag{c}
\bigcup_{k\in K}\operatorname{cl}(S_k)\subseteq \operatorname{cl}\left(\bigcup_{k\in K}S_k\right),
$$
and
$$\tag{d}
\operatorname{int}(S)=\big(\operatorname{cl}(S^C)\big)^C
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align} 
\operatorname{int}\left(\prod_{k\in K}S_k\right)
&=^{(e)} \left(\operatorname{cl}\left(\left(\prod_{k\in K}S_k\right)^C\right)\right)^C \\
&=^{(f)} \left(\operatorname{cl}\left(\bigcup\left(S_k^C\times\prod_{j\in K-k}X_j\right)\right)\right)^C \\
&=^{(g)} \left(\bigcup\operatorname{cl}\left(S_k^C\times\prod_{j\in K-k}X_j\right)\right)^C \\
&=^{(h)} \left(\bigcup\left(\operatorname{cl}(S_k^C)\times\prod_{j\in K-k}X_j\right)\right)^C \\
&=^{(i)} \bigcap\left(\operatorname{cl}(S_k^C)\times\prod_{j\in K-k}X_j\right)^C \\
&=^{(j)} \bigcap\left(\left(\operatorname{cl}(S_k^C)^C\times\prod_{j\in K-k}X_j\right)\cup \left(\operatorname{cl}(S_k^C)\times X_j^C\times \prod_{\ell\in K-k-j}X_\ell\right)\right) \\
&=^{(k)} \bigcap\left(\operatorname{cl}(S_k^C)^C\times\prod_{j\in K-k}X_j\right) \\
&=^{(l)} \prod_{k\in K}\operatorname{cl}(S_k^C)^C\\
&=^{(m)} \prod_{k\in K}\operatorname{int}(S_k),
\end{align}
$$
where in (e) we applied (d); in (f) we applied (b); in (g) we applied (c) modified with the equality; in (h) we applied (*); in (i) we applied De Morgan; in (j) we applied (b) again; in (k) we applied $X_j^C=\varnothing$; in (l) we applied a not given formula; and in (m) we applied (d) again.

> Question: Is the claim (a) correct? Are the used result (b) and (c) modified with the equality (I need the equality) correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim a) is wrong as soon as you do not have finitely many sets, because a product of open subsets is then not open in the product set with the product topology. 
There are, however, other topologies one can use on a product space, such as the box topology. 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology

The issue in your proof is at step (g), because closure does not commute with reunion in general — only with finite reunion.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. I suppose that as you say a) is correct for a family of finitely many sets, but also for any family of sets where only finitely many $S_k$ differ from $X_k$.  I need the result for this last combination. Do you agree with this patch?

Comment: Yes, your proof works when $S_k \neq X_k$ for at most finitely many $k$.